# Easiest effective way to use reed fence

Tags: fence

I bought 2 of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FORUNO) from home depot (except they are like 16' wide instead of 25' and incidentally only $24):

[image]

I am doing a "pallet project" wherein I've built a "tiki hut" bar out of old pallets, within a large area inside of metal pipes from the 1950's used (I think) for clotheslines:

[image: yard]

I don't necessarily feel like it has to be enclosed (fenced) on all 4 sides, just the 2 shorter sides of the rectangle.

I put one up on one end by leaning it against the metal poles then putting 4 tall skinny wooden stakes in on each side to hold it up straight. This did OK, but not great -- it's still loose and slumps a bit. I think the wind will blow the whole thing over this weekend.

Comment: Consider using cable ties to attach the reed fence to the posts.   If it slumps in the middle after pulling it as tight as possible, consider weaving twine through fence near the top, tying one end to a metal post, then pulling the twine taut and then tying the other end to the metal post.

Comment: @alfreema That's a good idea